# XSLT: Getting attribute Value in a nested when

Tags: html, xml, xslt, nested

Hi,
I am trying to extract attribute value from a xml using xslt. The snippets are below.

XSlt to extract the data from attributes . Used when loop to extract attribute data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="//catalog/cd/title/artist/country/item/@id='mod1'">
                <td>asdfg</td>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="//catalog/cd/title/artist/country/item/item/@id='up1'">
                    <td>
                      <xsl:value-of select="//catalog/cd/title/artist/country/item/item/@value" />
                    </td>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise/>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise/>
            </xsl:choose>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML data to be parsed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>
      <artist>
        <country>

          <item type="layer" id="mod" title="Mod" result="pass">
            <item type="measure" id="up" title="Up" value="10" unit="dBm" />
            <item type="measure" id="down" title="Down" value="9.6" unit="dBm" />

          </item>

          <item type="layer" id="mod1" title="Mod1" result="pass">
            <item type="measure" id="up1" title="Up" value="100" unit="dBm" />
            <item type="measure" id="down1" title="Down" value="9.60" unit="dBm" />

          </item>

        </country>
      </artist>
    </title>
  </cd>

</catalog>
```

Expected Output and Actual Output Below:

```
Expected output:

My CD Collection

Title  |    Artist
asdfg  |    100




Actual Output:

My CD Collection

Title  |    Artist
asdfg  |    10
```

Would be really thankful for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the logic in your XSLT is saying:

- If *any* item id is mod1

  - Then show a table cell with the value "asdfg"
  - And if *any* item's item ID is up1
  - Then show the `value` attribute of the first item's item in the document

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <xsl:variable name="mod1"
                          select="//catalog/cd/title/artist/country/item[@id = 'mod1']" />
            <xsl:if test="$mod1">
              <td>asdfg</td>
              <xsl:variable name="up1" select="$mod1/item[@id = 'up1']" />
              <xsl:if test="$up1">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$up1/@value" />
                </td>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As XSLT goes, this isn't very representative of what well-written XSLT looks like, but I am putting it here as an example because I assume that this is not your ultimate goal and that you are trying this as a step toward your final goal.

For the next step, I suggest opening up a new question.